# Downloading and installing an APK using volley

Tags: java, android, apk, android-volley, kotlin

I'm tring to download an update over the web. This is with the latest volley version. I'm using a `Stringrequest` at the moment.

```
class UpdateService : IntentService("Update Serivce") {
companion object {
    val VERSION_URL = "<version url>"
    val FILE_URL = "<apk url>"
    val LOG_TAG = "UPDATE"
    fun initialize(context: Context) = context.startService(Intent(context, UpdateService::class.java))
}

/**
 * Checks remote for an update
 */
override fun onHandleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Retrieving new version")
    // Get version number
    NetworkService().get(Uri.parse(VERSION_URL),
            Response.Listener { success(it) },
            Response.ErrorListener {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Failed to update ${it.toString()}")
                FirebaseCrash.report(it)
            })
}

private fun success(it: String?) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Remote version: $it")
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Local version: ${BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME}")

    if (!it.equals(BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME)) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Fetching new update")
        NetworkService().get(
                Uri.parse(FILE_URL),
                Response.Listener { installUpdate(it) },
                Response.ErrorListener {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "failed to get new APK")
                    FirebaseCrash.report(it)
                }
        )
    }
}

private fun installUpdate(it: String) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "retrieved update")

    val file = File(this.externalCacheDir, "update.apk")

    if(!file.exists()){
        file.createNewFile()
    }

    file.writeBytes(it.toByteArray())

    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive")
    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Installing")

    startActivity(intent)
}
```

}

When launching the installing activity, I will get a parse error from android.

[image: can't parse]

How can I download and save the file as an usable APK with volley?

Comment: check the apk's minimum version and your phone vesrion

Comment: I'm quite literally using the same device as I am using for development. this is not the issue here.

Comment: Is it the signed apk? Have you enabled `unknown resources` setting?. In some case if the apk file is not downloaded correctly/fully then this error may occurs.

Comment: This APK is signed and unknown resources are allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the directories. I tried writing to a cache directory, and installing from there. Change the directory to `context.getExternalFilesDir(<Appname>, "update.apk")` and it will install without a problem.